# Cannot stop autofs on FC19

Tags: fedora, usb, autofs

I'd like to temporarily disable autofs on my fedora 19 x86 install. I would like to insert USB drives without them auto-mounting. Typing:

```
service autofs stop
```

Returns:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop  autofs.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit autofs.service not loaded.
```

Typing:

```
chkconfig autofs off
```

Returns:
    error reading information on service autofs: No such file or directory

I see there are ways to stop it from running at startup, but I want it to load at startup. I need to be able to stop & start it without logout/reboot.

Answer (score 1):

To stop `autofs`:

```
$ sudo service autofs stop
```

To stop it permanently:

```
$ sudo chkconfig autofs off
```

However, I do not believe the automounting service `autofs` is what's mouting the USB drives, rather they're done by GNOME.

If you bring up Nautilus you can access the dialog to change this. It's in the menu *Edit* -> *Preferences*, under the *Media* tab. From this tab you can control various aspects of automounting of CD, DVD, and USB, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, like I said in my post, running those commands, as root, does not stop or start the service.

Comment: @hotkarl - I think you missed my point. The automatic mounting of USB drives is done by a different system that's part of GNOME. The autofs service is for mounting directories typically from a samba or NFS share. It can mount other things, but is generally not used for this.

Comment: Oh my bad!! I see now.. I'm actually using MATE, and don't have the USB option in that path, but I'll figure something out. Thanks!!

Comment: Try using the tool `mateconf-editor` then navigate the tree `/apps/caja/preferences/media_automount`. You should be able to disable it from there.